# How to set visibility instantly after button press

Tags: android, progress-bar

I want to have a progressbar running instantly after i pressed a button. 
At the moment the progressbar start showing after everything, that the button triggers is finished.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == etLocation){
        etLocation.setText("");

    }
    if (view == btnGo){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } });

        Thread buttonpress = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run()
            {
                buttonGo();
            }
        });

        buttonpress.run();
        try {
            buttonpress.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    if (view == datePicker){
        new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, date, myCalendar
                .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
    }
}
```

the visibility of the progressbar is set to INVISIBLE from the beginning on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == etLocation){
        etLocation.setText("");

    }
    if (view == btnGo){
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {

            } });

        Thread buttonpress = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run()
            {
                buttonGo();
            }
        });

        buttonpress.run();
        try {
            buttonpress.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    if (view == datePicker){
        new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, date, myCalendar
                .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: put `progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` above `if (view == etLocation){`

Comment: but i want it to execute only when the btngo is pressed

Comment: try putting progressbar above `buttonGo();`